# jQuery push and each doesn't seem to work?

Tags: jquery, push, each

I'm pushing to an array in jQuery and I can't do `.each` on that array afterwards, what is causing it?

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3btz14vq/)

```
var sections = [];
for (var j = 0; j < 15; j++) {
  sections.push("tests-" + j);
}

console.log(sections);  // this is a proper array

sections.each(function(){
  console.log("test");  // Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
});
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no `Array.prototype.each` method, either use [`Array.prototype.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) or jQuery `$.each` utility function. The `each` method that you are trying to use, belongs to jQuery objects and is used for iterating through the collections. You could use the `$(sections).each(fn)` syntax for creating jQuery object from an array and using it's `each` method, but that's a bad idea and should be avoided as the `sections` is not an array of DOM elements.

Note that jQuery has 2 `each` methods, one is a [utility function](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) and another is [a method of jQuery object](http://api.jquery.com/each/).

You can use `this.each` when you are defining a jQuery method as `this` in that *context* refers to a jQuery object which is an array-like object i.e. it has some of the Array methods but it's not a real array, it's a jQuery object, you can call the `.get()` method on the jQuery objects for getting the internal arrays, now the returned array has `.forEach()` method but not `.each()` method.

```
sections.forEach( function(elem) { console.log(elem); });
$.each(sections, function(index, elem) { console.log(elem); });
```

Comment: This is really confusing as I'm using this.each a few lines above and it seems to be working there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26962363/jquery-plugin-development-return-this-each-issue - could you please explain why does it work there and wouldn't in this scenario? Because the first one is a DOM element and here's just an JS-array?